# Firewalld POP3 service wont open on Centos 8

Tags: firewalld, centos8

Since the latest yum update (the first for a few months) POP3 has stopped working.

I have double checked that pop3 is listed on the public zone and sure enough it is:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https imap imaps pop3 smtp-submission smtps ssh
  ports: 25/tcp 80/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

But netstat does not show port 110 to be open:

```
netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2683/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      863/perl            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2683/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1355/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2683/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      862/nrpe            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2703/amavisd (maste 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2683/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10026         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2703/amavisd (maste 
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      2683/master         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:783                 :::*                    LISTEN      863/perl            
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      860/httpd           
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      2683/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1355/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      2683/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      860/httpd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5666                 :::*                    LISTEN      862/nrpe            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:10024               :::*                    LISTEN      2703/amavisd (maste 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:10026               :::*                    LISTEN      2703/amavisd (maste 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           659/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                659/chronyd
```

I have double checked the service file for POP3 exists and includes port 110 and it does.

If I listen on port 110 and ping, this shows up (but the port is reported as closed):

```
tcpdump -i any port 110
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
12:48:49.060706 IP 198.199.98.246.43347 > domain.net.pop3: Flags [S], seq 3072871086, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3789040058 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
12:48:49.060779 IP domain.net.pop3 > 198.199.98.246.43347: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3072871087, win 0, length 0
12:48:49.193808 IP 198.199.98.246.43350 > domain.net.pop3: Flags [S], seq 4058864357, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3789040092 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
12:48:49.193880 IP domain.net.pop3 > 198.199.98.246.43350: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 4058864358, win 0, length 0
12:48:49.327749 IP 198.199.98.246.43351 > domain.net.pop3: Flags [S], seq 1901081854, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3789040125 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
12:48:49.327824 IP domain.net.pop3 > 198.199.98.246.43351: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1901081855, win 0, length 0
```

If I check mail there is a similar dump but nothing in logged by Dovecot.

Comment: If the port is not open no service is running that is listening on it. Start your pop3 service.

Comment: I have restarted postfix and dovecot

Comment: postfix has nothing to do with POP3. Check the configuration and the logs of dovecot.

Comment: The logs are empty for Dovecot

Comment: Well without log entries or error message when the service is started there is no way to find out why it's not running.

Comment: Agreed, so I seem pretty stuffed, not many options at the moment.

Comment: You should provide the complete output when you restart the service as well as the latest log entries. Information you think irrelevant might actually be helpful.

Comment: Stop using 110 and switch to a secure port.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it.

Comment: FYI I tried 995 and the same problem.

Comment: I have reinstalled Dovecot and it is working now.